# FancyBox3 load images from an array and display thumbnails

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I currently have a JSON request that returns a list of images which I assign to an array named as "photosArray"

First I receive this request and add each item to the array item in the format:

`{src: 'www.mysite.com/image1.jpg};`'

And then I call the fancybox.open

```
 $.fancybox.open(photosArray,
            {
            buttons: ["thumbs", "close"],
            protect: true,
            transitionDuration: 1000,

            thumbs: {
                autoStart: true
            }
        },

        );
```

That works, the images are displayed, however I can not display thumbnails for the images, even adding the option `thumbs: {autoStart: true}`

In the examples I have seen, in order to display thumbnails, it is necessary to use data attributes in tags something like `data-fancybox="images" data-thumb=" small-image.jpg"`, but this is not an option because I do not display links or images on the page, just a link "View all images"

I would like to use the same full size images for the thumbnails.

So I kindly ask: how could I display thumbnails loading images from array in fancybox3.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that adding "thumb" to the array item causes the thumbnails to be displayed.

```
{src: 'www.mysite.com/image1.jpg', thumb: 'www.mysite.com/image1_small.jpg'};
```